# Set-PnPSearchSettings Access is denied error

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, sharepoint-search

I am trying to update placeholder text of a search box using `Set-PnPSearchSettings -Scope Site -SearchBoxPlaceholderText "My search"` but it is giving me ServerUnauthorizedAccessExceptionaccess: access is denied error for certain sites. I have a hub and this seem to worked on the hub site but when I try to run this on associated hub sites I get this error. But on a different tenant I can run this with no problem on both hub site and associated hub sites. I am a site collection administrator for all of the sites. I am on SharePoint Online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following pnp powershell to check if the custom script for this site has been enabled, [which will make some features unavailable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script):

```
$SiteUrl="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Team1"
$UserName="julie@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName $UserName -Message "Please enter password for $UserName"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $cred
Get-PnPTenantSite -Url $SiteURL |select DenyAddAndCustomizePages
```

To allow custom script on a particular site:

```
Set-PnPSite -Url $SiteURL -NoScriptSite $false
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Julie_MSFT